# Почему у Object прототипом является функция?

Tags: javascript

На сколько я понимаю, у js  ниже по цепочке прототипов, после Object уже ничего нет.
Однако, если у Object посмотреть прототип через метод `getPrototypeOf`, то нам вернет `ƒ () { [native code]  }`. Получается в js у Object протоип это функция?

Как это понять?

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)); // ƒ () { [native code]  }
```

Comment: Потому что это функция (Более того, это consructor). Вы можете например вызвать `new Object(42)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typeof Object === 'function'
```

Вполне логично, что у функции, прототипом является функция.

Чтобы получить `null` нужно подниматься выше по цепоче:

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))))
```

Также можно отметить, что прототипом объектов является `Object.prototype`, а не `Object`, и если брать прототип именно этого объекта получается `null` как и указано.

```js
console.log(Object.prototype)
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype))
```

Comment: > Вполне логично, что у функции, прототипом является функция.


Тогда получается, что в js все является функциями, а не объектами?

Comment: @overus, конечно нет.

Comment: @overus, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.